# Thread safe adding of subitem to a ListView control

Tags: .net, multithreading, listview, addition

I'm trying to convert an old Windows Forms Application to a WPF application.

The following code no longer compiles under C# .NET 4.0:

```
// Thread safe adding of subitem to ListView control
private delegate void AddSubItemCallback(
  ListView control,
  int item,
  string subitemText
);

private void AddSubItem(
  ListView control,
  int item,
  string subitemText
) {
  if (control.InvokeRequired) {
    var d = new AddSubItemCallback(AddSubItem);
    control.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, item, subitemText });
  } else {
    control.Items[item].SubItems.Add(subitemText);
  }
}
```

Please help to convert this code.

Comment: Use Dispatcher.CheckAccess and Dispatcher.Invoke instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the [following blog post](http://blog.somecreativity.com/2008/01/10/wpf-equivalent-of-invokerequired/) will help you. In WPF you use `Dispatcher.CheckAccess`/`Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    // You are on the GUI thread => you can access and modify GUI controls directly
    control.Items[item].SubItems.Add(subitemText);
}
else
{
    // You are not on the GUI thread => dispatch
    AddSubItemCallback d = ...
    control.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new AddSubItemCallback(AddSubItem)
    );
}
```

Comment: The Code: control.Items[item].SubItems.Add(subitemText); no longer compiles under .NET 4.0 WPF.  I get "Cannot resolve "SubItems".